# 4k Display Experience 18.04

Tags: 4k-monitor

I'm just going to compare this to the Apple 5k display experience.

The Apple displays look great I am assuming because there is some under the hood upscaling going on, so text and certain other things are not too small. But it still retains 5k or whatever beautifully. No clue whether this is taken care of on the hardware or software level.

On 18.04 with my 4k displays everything is ultra tiny, basically unusable without user modification. I can upscale the text using tweaks and some other tricks but it just does not look anywhere near as good as the Apple display. Also upscaling EVERYTHING looks awful as well.

Is this the same with all distros? Any recommendations are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I use top left FHD TV, top right 4K TV and bottom right 17" laptop FHD. It took a few hours of tweaking but I'm happy. Only problem are videos full screen on 4K TV is 1 frame every 30 seconds instead of 30 frames per second if almost full screen.

Comment: Avoid snap apps - find a repository version and install from there. snaps do not respect your theme including scaling etc so they often appear unusably tiny. It's a bit of a pain and a known problen that is being worked on, but until they fix it, that is what we're stuck with for the time being.